# Remove specific image from cache?

Tags: image, caching

Is there a way to "uncache" an image file?  I don't want to add a cache buster to the image src (it is a user avatar image) since I don't want to have to load the image on every page view.  Basically the problem is that when a user uploads a new avatar, it won't show up until they reload the page since the old one is still in cache with the same filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the filename unique (such as a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)). When the user uploads a new image, save it with a new GUID as the filename:

```
save to => "avatars/bd25298e-b537-48e1-a002-35c26e0536be.gif"
```

Comment: Well the way I have everything setup is that the filename is just in the form of username.png.

Comment: @James that's the problem. You need to add a column to your users table (or equivalent) for "avatar" which stores the filename.

Answer (score 0):

pass a unique key (randomly generated key) when upload a file name .

Answer (score 0):

You can append time or random number at the end of image URL.Using Jquery or Javascript.

Here E.G.: `<img src="/image/jit.gif?version=2" >`

Some thing like this.
 Browser pick up new version of image from server.It working for me 100%.